# TYPO3: add content element from hidden page via typoscript

Tags: typo3, record

When I hover over the content element (a login form) on the hidden page, I see its ID: 248. So here's my code within the extension template:

```
temp.contentElement = RECORDS
temp.contentElement {
  tables = tt_content
  source = 248
}
```

According this link
https://kuttler.eu/en/post/include-typo3-content-on-every-page/
that should work. But it doesn't. The element doesn't show up. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You should have this :

```
lib.loginForm = RECORDS
lib.loginForm {
  tables = tt_content
  dontCheckPid = 1
  source = 248
}
```

And then you can call it in your fluid template like this :

`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginForm" />`

Comment: So how do you add it in your page?

Comment: On the page where I want to show the element I've created a new extension template. Then I've copied the code above into the "Setup:" textbox.

Comment: do I need to activate something like css_styled_content in order to be able to access "tt_content"?

Comment: @user3182532 no. The database table `tt_content` must exist.